# Problems to get AccesToken of Strava with flutter_appauth

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, appauth, strava

I am developping an application with flutter with a single button which target is to obtain the accessToken and the refreshToken of an Strava user. Once I have those tokens, my idea is to call the Straba API to get information about the user.

I have read the docs of the [strava API](https://developers.strava.com/docs/getting-started/) and the docs of flutter_appauth . I have also followed the [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/) suggested by flutter_appauth

My code is based on the flutter_appauth [example](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/).

I have created an Strava Application:

[Strava APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydp1J.png) and
[Strava APP2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiLCr.png)

I have configured my Flutter project as follows, so when the user clicks the button the following code is executed:

```
const String DOMAIN = 'www.strava.com';
const String CLIENT_ID = '76520';

const String REDIRECT_URI = 'com.auth0.flutterdemo://login-callback';

Future<void> loginAction() async {

try {
  final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
      await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
    AuthorizationTokenRequest(
      CLIENT_ID,
      REDIRECT_URI,
      additionalParameters: <String, String>{
        'approval_prompt': 'force',
      },
      serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
        'https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize',
        'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
      ),
      scopes: <String>['read'],
    ),
  );
} on Exception catch (e, s) {
  debugPrint('login error: $e - stack: $s');
}
```

I have managed to show the Strava Authorization screen and to go back to the Application:

[Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM0ce.png) and [Go back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ScjK.png)

But the following error is returned back:

```
I/flutter (10911): login error: PlatformException(authorize_and_exchange_code_failed, Failed to authorize: 
[error: null, description: JSON deserialization error], null, null) - stack: #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
    package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
    I/flutter (10911): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
    package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:166
    I/flutter (10911): <asynchronous suspension>
    I/flutter (10911): #2      MethodChannelFlutterAppAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode
    package:flutter_appauth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_flutter_appauth.dart:32
    I/flutter (10911): <asynchronous suspension>
    I/flutter (10911): #3      _MyAppState.loginAction
    package:flutterdemo/main.dart:169
    I/flutter (10911): <asynchronous suspension>
    I/flutter (10911): #4      Login.build.<anonymous closure>
    package:flutterdemo/main.dart:86
    I/flutter (10911): <asynchronous suspension>
    I/flutter (10911):
```

I have tried to get the AccessToken in two steps:

```
final AuthorizationResponse result = await appAuth.authorize(
        AuthorizationRequest(
          CLIENT_ID,
          REDIRECT_URI,
          additionalParameters: <String, String>{
            'approval_prompt': 'auto',
          },
          serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
            'https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize',
            'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
          ),
          scopes: <String>['read'],
          // promptValues: ['login']
        ),
      );
      print('RESULT ${result}');
```

This step works OK. It returns an AuthorizationResponse whith authorizationCode and codeVerifier. When I try to get the token:

```
final AuthorizationTokenResponse token = await appAuth.token(
        TokenRequest(
          CLIENT_ID,
          REDIRECT_URI,
          authorizationCode: result.authorizationCode,
          codeVerifier: result.codeVerifier,
          serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
            'https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize',
            'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
          ),
        ),
      );
```

The same previous error is thrown. ¿Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I am new to flutter and to OAuth2.

Comment: we have the same problem. Did you find a solution to this question that you can share with us.

Comment: Yes. I used flutter_web_auth library. It is super easy to use and the example of the documentation is good. If you use that library you will have to define an intent-filter  (read the docs) and complete the part:  YOUR_CALLBACK_URL_SCHEME_HERE. For example, un the Strava api I defined the callbak as: callback andYOUR_CALLBACK_URL_SCHEME_HERE as com.example.flutter://callback and It worlks!

Comment: If you want to strictly use flutter_appauth, I think that you could open the project with Android Studio and debug the library in order to know why that error is thrown. In my case, I decided to use flutter_web_auth library to obtain the authorisation code and once I got the authorisation Code, I did a normal rest call to obtain the tokens. Give It a try and if you have problems, I Will try to help.